# Email Users When Their ID Selected in Task Field

Tags: 2010

I have a task list which has multiple fields users can select usernames from the corporate contact list. This is through a column field (person or group).

Is there a way to have all users who are selected through this process to be emailed whenever a task is created?

For example, if I have 5 fields of this sort, and select John, Al, Alice, Joe, and Tom for these five fields when creating the task, how do I automatically email all five of them upon task creation (similar to the "assigned" feature of issues)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think creating a SP Designer list workflow would work best here.

Comment: I don't know that this works in my particular situation but it does answer my question..